# StructureMap EnrichWith without specifying concrete class

Tags: decorator, structuremap

I have three assembly:

1. Interfaces
2. Implementations
3. Authorizations

My Authorizations assembly contains decorators for the different Interfaces and Implementations.

I know I can use something like that to the the decorating:

```
For<ISomething>
.Use<ConcreteSomething>
.EnrichWith<ISomething>((ctx, r) => new ConcreteSomethingDecorator));
```

But in my situation, I have a registry in my Implementations assembly and a registry in my Authorizations assembly. (I don't want my Authorization and Implementations assembly knowing the other one).

I don't want my Authorizations assembly having a reference to the Implementations assembly, so I am looking for something like that:

```
For<ISomething>
.EnrichWith<ISomething>((ctx, r) => new ConcreteSomethingDecorator));
```

In my bootstrapper, I want to add the AuthorizationRegistry using a flag to skip it in debug mode.

My question (finally!): Is it possible to enrich an Interface without specifying a concrete class?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do this!

Simply using EnrichAllWith instead of EnrichWith!